# PHP Redirect After File Upload

Tags: php, redirect, file-upload, post-redirect-get

I've got a bit of a problem. I am not the best when it comes to PHP and I want something done in PHP. Haha. I have made a video upload script and I want it to send the user to the video they uploaded once it finishes.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
/* if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is a movie/video - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not a movie/video.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
} */
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too small.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded."; // This is the line where it uploads

Comment: Basiclly use `header('Location: path/to/video'); exit;`

Comment: Of course, yet, how can I make it  so it adds the new video's extension and  file path? Like, one it's uploaded it'll redirect to 'header('Location: uploads/fileuploaded.extension'); exit;'

Comment: `header("Location: $target_file");` but you have to change the filepath to an url like: from `your/path/myroot/videos/video.xy` to `my.domain.com/videos/video.xy`

Answer (score 0):

header("Location: $target_file"); but you have to change the filepath to an url like: from your/path/myroot/videos/video.xy to my.domain.com/videos/video.xy

Thanks JOUM! It worked. :)